# Websphere 8.0 and Java 1.7

Tags: java, websphere, java-7, websphere-portal

we're currently using Websphere 8.0.0.7 which runs with Java 1.6.
Unfortunately, some of the portlets we would like to integrate into the portal need Java 1.7 to run.

Is there any (simple) way to use Java 1.7 under Websphere 8.0.0.7? I found a lot of answers for Websphere 8.5, but especially not for 8.0. Is the use of 1.7 even possible?

Thanks a lot for your effort!

Philipp

Comment: `V8.5` supports java SE 7 http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1206_alcott/1206_alcott.html

Comment: Hey Jigar, thanks for your reply! As mentioned I would like to use SE7 in Websphere 8.0 environment. I haven't found any information for this, but do not think that this is possible.. Anyway I would like to have some recommendations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WAS 8.0 will not support JAVA 7 (1.7).

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1121441746890&osPlatform=Windows#prereqs-Java

JAVA shipped with WAS versions.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002

The JAVA 7 is  supported from WAS 8.5.x and is shipped as optional feature as default for 8.5.x is also JAVA 6.

Answer (score 3):

WebSphere 8.0 supports Java 1.6 not 1.7. There's nothing you can do about this.

See the version support chart here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_history