# Possible to use jdk1.7 in websphere 8.0?

Tags: java-7, websphere-8

Is there any plugins available to use jdk 1.7 in websphere 8.0. Am aware that it won't support jdk1.7. But still want to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616653/websphere-8-0-and-java-1-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must use Java 1.6 with WebSphere Application Server 8.0.  If you need to use Java 1.7, simply upgrade the application server to version 8.5 where the use of jdk 1.7 is supported.